# Two Redmine 1.4 instances on same machine with very different performance on WEBrick

Tags: windows-server-2003, redmine, webrick

I installed Redmine 1.4 on Windows Server 2003 and MySQL. As after some time the instance became used by more people, I needed another one for testing (i.e. a development environment). As I also wanted to be able to test plugins without the risk of destroying the production Redmine instance, I copied the original Redmine (say `redmine_prod`) folder to another one (say `redmine_devel`). I created a new, empty Redmine database for `redmine_devel`. I only defined `production` environment in the first one and `development` in the second. Both instances run on Webrick started as Windows service, on different ports. Yet, there is a big difference in performance of both these instances - the old, production one runs very fast, whereas development runs slowly (several seconds to bring up pages, which doesn't alter with time).

I also tested running `redmine_devel` on thin server, which doesn't improve the performance a bit.

What can be the reason? They both run in literally same conditions.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's the default log level for environments other than `production` in Redmine. I.e. `production` uses `:info` as default, whereas other environments use `:debug`. This can be altered by editing `config\environments\[your_env].rb` and adding:

config.logger.level = Logger::INFO

to the chosed environment. There are also other options available, naturally.